# How to position the cursor in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, settext, cursor-position

In My app I'm using AutoCompleteTextView.
When the user select a result item, one of the option is inserting the selected text into the AutoCompleteTextView.
After inserting text, the cursor returns to the initial position.
How can i position it in the end of the inserted text?
Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: please put related code here.

Comment: autoCompleteTextView.setText(title);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try `setSelection(int index)`, it looks like what you are looking for

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

I can do better with your code. You probalby need to choose the good listener to use it

Comment: mEditTextLocation.setSelection(mEditTextLocation.getText().toString().trim().length());// End point Cursor